# Why is Word displacing text like this when inserting text boxes in-line?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

[image: Screenshots]

As you can see in the above screenshots, I start off with the cursor, i.e., insertion point, **below** the line of existing text.  However, after inserting the text box at that insertion point (with layout option set to "Inline with text"), for some inexplicable reason it ends up **above** the line of text, displacing the contents and pushing it below itself.

Can someone please shed some light on what's happening here?  How do I avoid this behavior?

Comment: can you please share more details on how you insert the second text box? After clicking into the line after the second list point, do you simply press CTRL+V to insert a copied box? Does it immediately jump to the first list point? Does maybe an AutoCorrect box appear? Are you sure, that the second text box also kept the text wrapping setting "In line with text"?

Comment: @Loeli Yes, I simply use CTRL+V, and yes it shows the inline-with-text property carries over, despite immediately appearing in the line above the insertion point's.  I don't recall seeing an auto-correct box, but even if there is I would have checked if the other options resolve the issue, which was not the case.

Comment: In a different comment you mentioned that you are inserting your breaks with SHIFT + ENTER. Can you please explain how the numbered list is entered? Is that a manual numbered list? Do you insert the text first and then click on the list numbering button? Also, do you insert your text boxes after the whole list has been created or while you are creating the list?

Comment: If possible, it might also but good if you insert the pictures in your question with formatting symbols activated and showing a larger portion of the screen incl. the styles gallery. Maybe this helps in some way. Also, if you can upload the doc to some cloud and provide the link, then we can have a look at it.

Comment: @loeli I added a comment in the other thread that explains my entire process.  Regarding how the numbered list bulleting is exactly applied, I enter the first number at the start of the list, followed by period, and then contents and hit enter.  This automatically formats the list, and from there I populate each additional entry.  Once everything is ready, *then* I go back and use `SHIFT-ENTER` in-between each line.

Comment: @Artiic When you insert a text box through the "Insert" tab, it is standard behaviour that it is NOT placed in-line and an anchor is shown. But as you already explained, you are copying a text box that already has the in-line setting applied and then the in-line setting will of course also be applied to the pasted text box. So, all this is as expected. Not sure why everyone seems to be so fixated on the anchor. This is only relevant if you overlooked to activate the in-line setting or if there is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert a text box through the "Insert" tab, it is standard behaviour that the text box is inserted with activated text wrapping (usually "Square"). At this point, the text box is NOT in-line and therefore (as harrymc pointed out) it might jump around and its position can be controlled with the blue anchor.

However, this should only happen for the first text box you insert. Reason: After you inserted the first text box, you changed the text wrapping options to in-line and since you are copying/pasting this text box (with all its settings), the following pasted text box should also have the in-line settings activated. So, there is no anchor and there should be no positioning problem.

If your positioning problem (text box jumping to a different paragraph) still persists, either your document or your Word application might have a bug. Please go ahead and create a completely new document and do your whole procedure in that new document. If everything works fine in the new document, then the previous one might be faulty. If the error persists in the new document, then it is either a user error or your Word application is faulty.

Answer (score 3):

First, some information about text-box positioning.

Text boxes are anchored to a paragraph in your document. You can see these anchors if you choose *File > Options > Display* and check the option for "Object Anchors".

An anchor looks like this : [image].

When the paragraph to which the text box is anchored moves,
so does the text box. Conversely, when the text-box moves,
so does the anchor.
To prevent this, right-click on the text-box and select
"Format AutoShape/Picture", go to the Layout tab, click Advanced,
and in the Position tab check "Lock anchor". Click OK twice
to terminate. This locks the anchor in its place, but the
text-box can still move and will keep its current distance
to the anchor when the anchor moves.

What you need to do is to enable the display of the text-box
anchor and then ensure that the anchor is attached to the
right paragraph to which you want it to be attached.

Comment: he is using "in line with text" which means anchoring cannot be the issue

Comment: @Loeli: He should then put it in line with the right paragraph.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, this is his issue. He starts out in the correct paragraph but the box automatically shift up even though "in line with text" is selected. I was thinking that maybe AutoCorrect does some weird things here, but not sure what's going on.

Comment: @Loeli: He may think it's the right paragraph, but the anchor of the text-box is not where he thinks.

Comment: And there is no need to downvote.

Comment: Sorry, a bit new here. Thought that this is commonly done when an answer seems to be not in line with the question (can't change vote, since it seems to be locked). But you're right, it might be the case that the second text box doesn't have "In line with text" activated which would make the anchoring a valid point. If "In line with text" is activated however, then the anchoring wouldn't be relevant.

Comment: @Loeli: Thanks for your return message. You can now reverse the vote (I edited my answer). In general, voting attitude is very personal. I myself only downvote answers that are plain wrong and useless to the poster and anyone else who happens upon them.

Comment: Got it - changed it back

Comment: @harrymc I will test and verify this, but I don't recall this behavior being defaulted in my past usage?  Did this change occur in recent editions?  Also, I'm not sure if it matters or not, but I forgot to mention in my OP that inbetween each bullet I am inserting a line return (via SHIFT+ENT) rather than carriage return, does this matter at all?

Comment: It might matter as regarding the placement of the text-box anchor.

Comment: @Arctiic using shift-enter does matter because it doesn't create a new paragraph,  and in that case the Anchor is still inserted at the beginning of the para. (I just checked). FWIW I think this behaviour has been the same ever since it became possible to "inline" textboxes, which is way back in Word XP (over 20 years ago), but there may well be some wrinkle I'm not aware of.

Comment: @jonsson not sure what I‘m overlooking here, but do you really also (same as harrymc) have an anchor visible when inserting the text box in-line? I never get an anchor when using in-line, which made sense to me so far, since the text box is already in the line with the text

Comment: @Arctiic Probably the reason for a certain amount of talking at cross-purposes! But how are you inserting on-line? The normal insert functions always seem to insert a floating object, so are you pasting or inserting from an autotext, or something else?

Comment: @jonsson Okay, I was concerned that might have been the case.  Oh and I was referring to the anchor feature being defaulted on, rather than the in-line positioning.

Comment: @loeli That's exactly what caused my confusion, I didn't recall this feature being enabled by default, but there *is* an anchor on-screen after inserting the textbox from `Insert > Text Box > Simple Text Box`.

Comment: @jonsson Let me back up and clarify: first I create the numbered list and format as desired.  Then, I created a single textbox using the method stated in my previous comment, and proceeded to modify the properties to how I want them to be.  From there, I copy the formatted textbox (which includes changing to in-line positioning) and I go the end of each number-bulleted line and, using `SHIFT+ENTER` I insert a line return (to preserve indentation and numbering order), and then I paste the text box.  I like to get all this done before I start filling in the contents rather than doing it as I go.

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure what happened, but now that I'm looking at it again, this time when I insert a new textbox and set positioning to `in-line`, *the anchor goes away*, and the relevant sections in the formatting also becomes greyed out.  Nothing moves or jumps around as I insert/change the size of the textboxes, which again was the behavior I expected.  So I'm pretty sure this is the *intended* behavior, but when I created the OP I distinctly recall the anchor was visible when I created the textbox, and when I changed to in-line they went away (per screenshot); however, it sounds like...

Comment: ...for whatever reason, the anchoring behavior still persisted?  Could it be a bug?  I would consider human error and hold reasonable doubt for human error, but you can clearly see in the screenshots that the anchor is not visible (I never toggled it off in the Settings), yet the behavior was still present as I was reproducing the issue to take the screenshots.

Comment: @Arctiic don't forget that it is possible that the nchor display was turned off altogether. (Unless it wasn't!)

Comment: @jonsson unless there is an out-of-box shortcut I might have accidentally invoked, it was **not** turned off.